# aiohttp, raising an error on GET, can't send GET request to https website

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have this code part that sends GET request:

```
proxy_auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth('proxy-username', 'proxy-password')
    async with session.get('https://google.com', headers=headers, proxy='http://proxy_url.com', proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as response:
        html = await response.text()
```

The problem is when I'm trying to GET `https` website it returns this exception:

```
ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host google.com:443 ssl:default [The parameter is incorrect]
```

This exception is thrown only when the website is provided by `https`, with `http` there's no exceptions.
The proxy is `https` but aiohttp only accepts `http` proxy, but I know there's some tricks to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that problem. It happens because of the `aiohttp` library itself so we need to change the `Event Policy Loop` to `asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()`

Like that:

```
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```